# Chaining predicates into one using the Stream API

Tags: java, stream, predicate

I have a list of predicates (`List<Predicate<String>>`) which I want to chain into one using `or` methods. How can I use the Stream API to achieve that?

Comment: What did you try? Why do you need to use the Stream API here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to join them all together with `or`, yielding a single `Predicate<String>`. Like this:

```
List<Predicate<String>> predicates = getPredicates();

Predicate<String> p = predicates.stream()
    .reduce(s -> false, Predicate::or);
```

Comment: Just curios, why is the identity false? It depends may be on context, but i should have tought it must be true when reducing the list using `OR` and for example using it in a stream as a filter.

Comment: @Eritrean If the identity were `s -> true` then the combined predicate would always succeed, regardless of the list of predicates.